# correlation coefficient from linear mixed effect model

Tags: correlation, mixed-model

I was hoping I could get someone's help with regard to how I might compute a correlation coefficient from a linear mixed effect model?

My basic problem is that I have two variables of interest (i.e. 2 gene expression modules), some covariates of no interest that I want to model out, and whereby the gene expression measurements are done at different sites in the brain (hence this is the random effect). What I'd ideally want is a measure of similarity such as a correlation coefficient that tells me how related the 2 gene expression modules are after running a linear mixed effect model that accounts for the random effect and all the covariates.

Currently I use the MATLAB function fitlme to do linear mixed effect modeling, but the output I get from that function doesn't readily have something like the correlation coefficient available, so I'd like to know how I might compute the correlation coefficient or something similar to this that I could use as a metric of similarity.

Comment: Em... Are you consider doing a [partial correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_matrix_inversion) first? Returning correlation coefficient is not what any linear mixed effects model is primarily designed to do. These being R's `lmer/lme` or MATLAB's `fitlme/nlmefit` functions... Also as your brain regions are probably not random you might want to treat them as fixed effects. You can always look at their residuals if they are correlated but this is quite indirect.

Comment: Yes, this is like getting a partial correlation from the model.  I know you can do this with a standard GLM, so I was wondering if there is an easy way to compute this from any output from mixed effect models.